# What are the block variables capturing?

Tags: ruby

One tutorial has this block of code:

```
h1 = ["a" => 111, "b" => 222]
h2 = ["b" => 333, "c" => 444]
h1.merge(h2) {|key, old, new| new}
# => ["a" => 111, "b" => 333, "c" => 444]
h1.merge(h2) {|key, old, new| old}
# => ["a" => 111, "b" => 222, "c" => 444]
```

We have a conflict with the merge. Two duplicate keys across our two arrays. `new` is capturing `h2`'s value for `"b"`, and outputting it forces it to take priority in the merge. Similarly, `old` is capturing `h1`'s value for `"b"`, and forces it to take priority.

Why are we seemingly only grabbing the values for `"b"`? Shouldn't the variables be grabbing the whole array(s)? Are the block variables context-sensitive and change function when used with `.merge` as opposed to, say, `.times`? Or is it that they change function when we're dealing with arrays instead of simple numericals? Or is it that they see a merge conflict and are like "we got to capture the point of conflict"? I thought that maybe trying to see what was in `key` would help,

```
h1.merge(h2) {|key, old, new| key}
# => ["a" => 111, "b" => "b", "c" => 444]
```

but it actually just made me more confused. Why is one variable capturing the key, whereas the others are capturing the two different values?

Comment: I'm quite new to ruby (and loving it) and this seems like in the 1st case it takes the keys one by one, if there are duplicates it uses the value of the second collection. In the second it does the same but takes the values of the 1st collection (old). What seems to be confusing you is that h1.merge() doesn't modify h1, it returns a new object. ruby is awesome :)  Do please note that I'm not 100% sure, thus commenting and hoping someone will manage to answer better (or approve this answer and make me happy :D)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's merging:  in `h1.merge(h2)`, 'h1' is the "old" hash, and 'h2' is the "new" one.  The block is called only for keys that have values in both hashes.  The block gets 3 arguments: each key and the corresponding values from each hash.   The logic in the block chooses which one to put in the output hash for that key.  Any key that is only in one hash goes straight into the output without being processed through the block.

You might better understand what's going on by running

```
 h1.merge(h2){|key,left,right| print "k=#{key} l=#{left} r=#{right} "}
```

From the [Ruby-Doc.org](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge) description:

> Returns a new hash containing the contents of other_hash and the
>   contents of hsh. If no block is specified, the value for entries with
>   duplicate keys will be that of other_hash. Otherwise the value for
>   each duplicate key is determined by calling the block with the key,
>   its value in hsh and its value in other_hash.

So to answer one of your specific questions, yes, the block is called conditionally, only for conflicting keys, unlike methods like .each or .delete_if, which are called for each key.

Comment: Okay! Okay, this clarifies a lot, actually. I think that the majority of my confusion was coming from the idea that blocks were working the same way here as they do for other methods; I see now that they don't. Thanks for your answer! I'll be looking more into block variables now. :)

Answer (score 1):

I would advise you to study how blocks and block variables work in ruby, because I think that this is what trips you up.

For example, this [resource](http://www.skorks.com/2009/09/using-ruby-blocks-and-rolling-your-own-iterators/) might prove helpful.

Comment: I think you're right! I guess I just didn't have the vocabulary ("blocks") to properly ask and research it before. Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

From the documentation of [merge](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Hash.html#method-i-merge). The three parameters `key, old, new` are used in this way:

- If `key` exists in only one of the hashes then the value from that hash is used to build the merge
- If `key` exists in both hashes then the returned value from proc (block) `{|key, old, new| key }` is returned, in this case is `key` which is the key to be inserted in the hash.

You could do other things such as `{|key, old, new| old - new }` to invoke a computation when there's a key conflict between the two hashes. Here's an example from the documentation of merge:

```
h1 = { "a" => 100, "b" => 200 }
h2 = { "b" => 254, "c" => 300 }
h1.merge(h2)   #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>254, "c"=>300}
h1.merge(h2){|key, oldval, newval| newval - oldval}
               #=> {"a"=>100, "b"=>54,  "c"=>300}
```